# BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged event not on Dispatcher Thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, timer, backgroundworker

I have the following code which updates my progress bar and status bar from a backgroundworker.  I run the same backgroundworker twice.  The first time I run it I call it from the MainWindow constructor it works fine.  At the end of the constructor I setup a timer to call the method every so often.

```
   System.Threading.TimerCallback timerCallback = new System.Threading.TimerCallback(RefreshWebDataTimer);
    timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
        timerCallback, null,
        Dictionary.MS_TIMER_FIRSTREFRESH_PERIOD,
        Dictionary.MS_TIMER_REFRESH_PERIOD);
```

When calling it from the timer I get the following error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in WindowsBase.dll Additional information: The calling thread
>   cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

I added some debug and indeed the Dispatcher Thread is on a different thread from the timer and the same thread from the original run.

```
   private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender,
            ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Current Thread: {0}", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Dispatcher Thread: {0}", progressBar.Dispatcher.Thread.ManagedThreadId);


            this.progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            this.progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            if (e.UserState != null)
            {
                this.statusBar.Text = e.UserState.ToString();
            }
        }
```

> Current Thread: 22 
>   Dispatcher Thread: 7

I was under the impression that the `ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted` events always ran on the main UI thread in order to solve this problem and be able to do UI updates.  Apparently, I misunderstand what is going on here.

I updated my solution to use the Dispatcher as follows:

```
private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender,
    ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new OneArgIntDelegate(updateProgressBar), e.ProgressPercentage);
    if (e.UserState != null)
    {
        progressBar.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new OneArgStrDelegate(updateStatusBar), e.UserState.ToString());
    }
}

private void updateStatusBar(string Text)
{
    this.statusBar.Text = Text;
}

private void updateProgressBar(int ProgressPercentage)
{
    this.progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    this.progressBar.Value = ProgressPercentage;
}
```

This solution worked but I thought the whole point of the BackgroundWorker was that I didn't have to do this. Can someone explain my incorrect assumption and what is really going on. Is there a way to do this WITHOUT the dispatcher by setting up the timer differently?

Thanks,

Harrison

Comment: where are you creating the BackgroundWorker?  It needs to be created on the thread that runs the dispatcher (usually the main thread).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was under the impression that the ProgressChanged and
>   RunWorkerCompleted events always ran on the main UI thread in order to
>   solve this problem and be able to do UI updates. Apparently, I
>   misunderstand what is going on here.

The BackgroundWorkers ProgressChanged is called back to the thread that owns the BackroundWorker, this is not aways the UI thread, When you create the `BackgroundWorker` the second time it is being created on another thread so the `ProgressChanged` will be invoked on the thread that created the `BackgroundWorker` in this case the timer thread.

- First Call: UIThread => BacgroundWorker => Progress => UIThread
- SecondCall: TimerThread => BacgroundWorker => Progress => TimerThread

You can ether invoke the `RefreshWebDataTimer` from the `Timer` to the UI thread or use a `DispatcherTimer` to ensure the `RefreshWebDataTimer` is called on the UI thread.

Option 1:

```
  timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
             (o) => Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)RefreshWebDataTimer),
             null,
             Dictionary.MS_TIMER_FIRSTREFRESH_PERIOD,
             Dictionary.MS_TIMER_REFRESH_PERIOD);
```

Option 2:

```
   timer = new DispatcherTimer(
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                DispatcherPriority.Background,
                (s, e) => RefreshWebDataTimer(),
                Dispatcher);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try that out.  That looks like a great solution.

Comment: I am attempting Option 1 but keep having a problem with `A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`.  The RereshWebDataTimer takes a parameter object so I restructured your solution to  `(o) => Dispatcher.Invoke((Action<object>)RefreshWebDataTimer)` but still no luck.  Can you please help?  Thanks.

Comment: I used option 2 and adjusted it as follows and it works

`timer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer(
               new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,Dictionary.MS_TIMER_FIRSTREFRESH_PERIOD),
               System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background,
               (s, e) => RefreshWebDataTimer(null),
               Dispatcher);`

Thanks for the help!!